# optimize cocos2d-js performance

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

my cocos2d game works fine on computer-browsers but quite slow on older mobile browsers ( like iPhone4 ) 
What can i do to improve performance?
For example: The Background consists of multiple ( eight ) Sprites which make up some kind of a console. I choose to do it like this to be able to re-arrange them on orientation change.
Also I put the whole game-logic into a class like

```
var Logic = cc.Class.extend({
 ctor:function(gamelayer) {
  this.game=gamelayer;  
  this.userObj={};
  this.x_tiles=8;
  this.y_tiles=8;
  //... and so on
 },
 prepare:function (nu_level){
   //code
 },
 ganeOver:function(){
  //code
 },
 // and so on

)}
```

is this bad or good or unimportant for performance?

thanks a lot.

Comment: If the code is working and you want to optimize/refactor it, you should ask question on [codereview.se] instead of main SO site. These type of questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: This would get closed as hypothetical code on Code Review, unless the `/...code...` parts were replaced with the actual, real working code. CR has their rules, too.

Comment: Instead of asking here **profile your code** and see for yourself